# Looping a for with variables on a shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh

I have the following script that SSH to a server with a key and makes a lot of stuff there.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh -i mykey.pem myuser@SERVER_IP << 'ENDSSH'
[A LOT OF STUFF]
ENDSSH
```

(which I run it with `sh scriptname.sh`)

Now I want to to the same in another server, so I've to SSH to two different servers (`ip_1` and `ip_2`) with two different `.pem` files (`mykey1.pem` and `mykey2.pem`).

So far I know how to loop the ips as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ip_list="ip_1 ip_2"

for ip in $ip_list; do
ssh -i mykey.pem myuser@$ip << 'ENDSSH'
[A LOT OF STUFF]
ENDSSH
done
```

but now I would like to loop also to get the proper pem file. How can I archieve this? Maybe with another list? Can someone provide me an elegant solution?

- `ip_1` should use `mykey1.pem`
- `ip_2` should use `mykey2.pem`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use mykey1.pem but ip_1.pem. Then it's easy: ssh -i $ip.pem myuser@$ip << 'ENDSSH'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using bash, you can use [associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A ip_list=(["ip_1"]="mykey1.pem" ["ip_2"]="mykey2.pem")

for ip in "${!ip_list[@]}"; do
  ssh -i  "${ip_list[$ip]}" myuser@"$ip" << 'ENDSSH'
[A LOT OF STUFF]
ENDSSH
done
```

Note that associative arrays, unlike regular indexed arrays, are not saved in a specific order, so there is no guarantee that `ip_1` will be processed before `ip_2`.

---

If you *need* to use a simple, POSIX compatible shell, create a file with the ip and key files, one per line:

```
$ cat iplist.txt
ip1 mykey1.pem
ip2 mykey2.pem
```

Then, use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r ip key; do
    ssh -i "$key" myuser@"$ip" << 'ENDSSH'
[A LOT OF STUFF]
ENDSSH
done
```

And run it with:

```
sh /path/to/script <  /path/to/iplist.txt
```

But if you go that route, [Stéphane's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508710/22222) is better.

Comment: I'm running it with `sh` (I cant change that), so it seems I cannot use arrays.

Comment: @Avión what do you mean? You have `#!/usr/bin/env bash` in your script. Just make the script executable (`chmod a+x /path/to/script`) and then run it directly: `/path/to/script`. Alternatively, run it with `bash /path/to/script`. The only reason you're using `sh` is because you're calling it with `sh /path/to/script`.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to use a `while IFS=, read -r` loop on a csv here-document.

```
#! /bin/sh -
while IFS=, read <&3 -r ip key; do
  ssh -i "$key" "$ip" << ENDSSH
  ...
ENDSSH
done 3<< ENDCSV
10.0.0.1,p1.pem
10.0.0.2,p2.pem
ENDCSV
```

Then you don't even need to require users to install bash. If portability is not a concern, you could use `zsh` instead which supports looping over more than one variable.

```
#! /usr/bin/env zsh
for ip key (
  10.0.0.1 p1.pem
  10.0.0.2 p2.pem
) ssh -i $key $ip << ENDSSH
  ...
ENDSSH
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original script can be made slightly more portable via `set` built-in, plus have ip and key go together as one string, colon separated. We later can use prefix and suffix removal to extract corresponding entry

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set positional parameters
# Example ip addresses
set -- 192.168.0.1:mykey1 192.168.1.1:mykey2

# iterating without specifying 'in' assumes positiona parameters
for host; do
    ssh -i ${host##*:}.pem myuser@${host%%:*} << 'ENDSSH'
[A LOT OF STUFF]
ENDSSH

done
```

Comment: set is not really helping here. You could just as well do `for host in 192.168.0.1:mykey1 192.168.1.1:mykey2; do`. Note that `:` is not the best choice of delimiter as it's found in IPv6 addresses. You also need to quote parameter expansions to prevent split+glob

Comment: All fair points. Semicolon could serve a better delimiter, maybe ?